# GAE is any good ? if yes then JAVA or Python?

Tags: java, python, google-app-engine

Basically I am coding websites in PHP from last year.
But now I want to use something else and GAE looks a good option.

So I want to know if GAE is good for making a little website to share favorite youtube videos ?

I have done single website in Python+Django few months back, it looks good to me.

But JAVA is the language that I want to learn too (never coded in JAVA since School days ).

Phew, it is hard to choose, so I need opinions !!

**Specifically :** Want to know if any glitch/problem in using either python or Java under GAE. Or if GAE is preferred or not. Not gonna make website for learning only, it will be for a client.

Comment: Opinions don't help much, since you're basically repeating opinions in your question.  GAE works.  Java works.  Python works.  If you want to use Java, why ask for more opinions?  Why not just use Java?  Do you have a **specific** reason for not using Java?  If you have a **specific** question, please UPDATE this to include your **specific** concerns.  Opinions are going to be useless.

Comment: "Want to know if any glitch/problem"?  Really?  Why ask us?  Why not check the bug reports for GAE?   http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list  That would be **fact** not opinion.

Comment: It is not always as simple as checking a bug list.  It may not obvious from reading the bug list that some java apps are having problems with slow startup times, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most people here are missing the fact that the question is really about App Engine, not java or python in general.

The Java and Python SDKs and App Engine runtimes have pretty much the same abilities at this point.  One caveat with the current java runtime is that if you use a lot of external libraries, your loading hits (the first time someone hits your website, and app engine has to spin up your app) can be a bit slow.

Comment: Just make sure to stick with Python 2.5.2. All the newer versions (2.6+) are not supported 'officially' by GAE.

Comment: python 2.7.2 is now supported if you were looking.

Answer (score 3):

Java and Python are both excellent languages. It is a matter of taste and believe which you choose.

- If you prefer a lightweight solution, use Python.
- If you have enterprise needs, **whatever that means**, use Java.

If you ask for my personal believe, my subjective stand-of-point is:

- Use Python wherever possible and stick to other languages if there is a need to.

So this is my opinion, but as S.Lott commented on your question:

> Opinions are going to be useless.

Comment: Well you answered perfectly ,am not agree with `Opinions are going to be useless.` .The line `If you prefer a lightweight solution, use Python.` yes this is exactly i need to know a website can be visited by millions in one sec. so it should be light weight.I still needs more opinions to choose better.

Comment: If your app needs to be maintained for a fair number of years I think documentation and unit tests are even more important for Python software that for Java software, which has part of the documentation in the method signature. Do take that into account when defining lightweight. If you write throw-away software that obviously is not important.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to learn Java, then use Java!

If you feel that Java is too verbose compared to Python, you could try Scala, which runs on the JVM like Java. Scala is more concise and well designed.

Answer (score 2):

You'll be able to accomplish the exact same results using either Python or Java.  Java is much more verbose than Python, which can make it have a bit of a steeper learning curve.  The fact that you have some experience in Django (which GAE's webapp is largely based on and which you can even use directly if you want) will make it easier for you to get the website up and running in the immediate term.

So again, it does depend on what you want to accomplish.  If your goal is to learn Java, then doing a project in Java is the best way to learn it.  If your main goal is to get the site up and running, Python will be a better choice as it will let you focus less on struggling with learning new Java syntax and more on simply getting the website off the ground.

Answer (score 1):

I would personally go with a Java based solution. If this is just a little website for yourself, then it would be a good idea to learn a new technology, in this case Java. Little projects like this are ideal for learning new technologies and seeing if they are suitable for you as a developer and other projects you may decide to do in the future

Answer (score 1):

You need an IRL mentor.